# How to protect react routing when session (stored cookie) is not accessible?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, routes

I'm looking for a efficient way to prevent unauthorized people from accessing specific routing paths.

The cookie that i get from the backend is not readable so i can't do much with it. 
I have two endpoints:

1. /token (POST) to get the cookie with the token
2. /account (GET) to get the username and role

Short explaination of what i did so far:

- Protected all routing by wrapping them with a PrivateRoute component
- A redux action is fired after user is attempting to log in. This action calls an api which returns a cookie (jwt) and the data of the user. Username and role will be saved into the 'authStore'. If login succeed the attribute 'isAuthenticated' in the same store is set to True. Only when this boolean is set to true, user can access the wrapped routes.

My problem:

If I close my tab and open a new one, the store resets (which is fine and normal). The cookie is still available tho. So for a good UX I would like to authenticate the user directly. At the moment the user is redirected to the login page. This makes sense because the PrivateRoute component is only accessible if the store attribute isAuthenticated is true. So the user has to login again to update the store.

I tried to dispatch an action in App.js from the method componentDidMount to get the user credentials directly but that didn't help. Since render() is being fired first it won't help.

This is my code:

App.js:

```js
export class App extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Action to retrieve user credentials (if available then saves it to the authStore and sets isAuthenticated to true)
    this.props.initloginRequest();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="d-flex flex-column h-100 w-100 bg-grey main-container">
        <Sprites className="d-none" />
        <Router>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" exact component={X1} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={X2} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/details" exact component={X3} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/finish" exact component={X4} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
export class PrivateRoute extends Component {
    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated, component, ...rest } = this.props;

        const renderComponent = (props) => {
            if (isAuthenticated) {
                const ComponentToShow = component;
                return <ComponentToShow {...props} />
            } else {
                return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
            }

        };

        return (
            <Route
                {...rest}
                render={renderComponent}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state) => ({
        isAuthenticated: state.authStore.isAuthenticated
    })
)(PrivateRoute);
```

There is a possible solution for this by making an api call to /account based on the status code it returns. Whenever the route is changed the call will be made so that is not really what i want. I just want a solution that requires one call at the beginning of the application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am facing a really similar problem and would like to know how this should actually be handled. At the moment I have been thinking just setting some internal authenticated state to true and then use that to handle routing logic. Every request to server will anyway include a session cookie in them and if they don't server wont return any sensitive data and the front-end internal auth state will be set to false. This doesn't sound like a good idea, but it's the best I've come up with so far :/

Comment: @zaplec I've solved this issue. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this issue by dispatching an action in index.js (src path):

```
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import { initloginRequest } from './actions/auth';

const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(initloginRequest())

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

This action calls an api and checks if the user is authenticated. So when it reaches my PrivateRoute component, it knows in which direction it should redirect the user.

You should set isFetching in your store/state on true till the action finishes to prevent the App.js from rendering your routes.

```
export class App extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    const { isFetching } = this.props

    if (isFetching) {
      return <div>Loading application...</div>
    }

    return (
      <div className="d-flex flex-column h-100 w-100 bg-grey main-container">
        <Sprites className="d-none" />
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          ...private route etc...
        </Switch>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    isFetching: state.authStore.isFetching,
  }),
  (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
  }, dispatch),
)(App);
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: So does that mean that you store the info about is the user logged in or not in your Redux store? Or does that make the authentication check on every render?

Comment: @zaplec I do store some user information in my redux store such as: role, isAuthenticated, name etc. The action i mentioned in index.js will be fired whenever the page refreshes. So one time as long you're using a single page application :)